# How to change background color in QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I want to give background color in my QGraphicsScene. For that, I have override drawBackground() method, and tried to set color but it is not working. Background color is not changing.
Here is my drawBackground() method.

Widget.h

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
protected:
    void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect);    
};
```

Widget.cpp

```
    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
        : QGraphicsView(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    
        view = new QGraphicsView(this);
        view->setScene(scene);
        view->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
        ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(view);
    }
    
   void Widget::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
   {
       painter->save();
       painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
       painter->restore();
   }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Which `QGraphicsView` do you want to set the background for -- the one you inherit from or the one you add to `ui->verticalLayout_2`?

Comment: @G.M. I want to set background for the ui->verticalLayout_2. So my background should be yellow.

Comment: Just use [`view->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::yellow)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#backgroundBrush-prop).

Comment: @G.M. Thank you for your reply. But I want to ask what is the difference between seeting background color through ui->verticalLayout_2 and overriding drawBackground() ?  And why my drawBackground() is not working ? What should I change there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems or, at least, inconsistencies.  Firstly your `Widget` class makes use of both inheritance *and* composition with regard to `QGraphicsView` in that it derived from `QGraphicsView` and has a `QGraphicsView` member.  That may be what you want but it seems unlikely.

Firstly, you say...

> I want to set background for the ui->verticalLayout_2. So my
> background should be yellow.

As per my comment, that can be easily done by simply using [`QGraphicsView::setBackgroundBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#backgroundBrush-prop)...

```
view->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::yellow);
```

The other issue is with your override of `drawBackground` in the `Widget` class.  Currently you have...

```
void Widget::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
    painter->restore();
}
```

But all that does is save the painter's state, set its brush to a solid yellow colour and then restore the state of the painter.  It's essentially a noop in that it doesn't actually draw anything.  If you really want to override the `drawBackground` member in this way then try something like...

```
void Widget::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::yellow));
    painter->drawRect(rect);
    painter->restore();
}
```

[As an aside, when overriding a virtual member in a derived class always use the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier.]